# ckeditor not showing in edit blade

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

``I am new in using ckeditor and working on simple crud application using ckeditor. it is working well in the create blade but not showing in the update blade.

here is my blade code

```
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.ckeditor').ckeditor();
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form  method = "post"  action="{{url('updateblog')}}" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
@method('PATCH')
<label for="title">Title</label>
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="title">{!!$blog ->title!!}</textarea><br>
</form>
```

Comment: is `{!!$blog ->title!!}` being html-escaped?

Comment: ya {!!$blog->title!!} is shown in the blade but in a textarea.

Comment: is ckeditor script available in current html page? eg open update page in browser and see if ckeditor script is indeed loaded. Then see the value if it is being html-escaped or not

Comment: i mean the ckeditor field is not showing up. {!!$blog->title!!} is rendered in textarea

Comment: console or inspectelement  and show the errors of ckedtior then i can help you .

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this worked for me:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="title">{{ $blog->title }}</textarea>
```

I hope i can help you.

Comment: Oh im sorry about that :*( @Alexirungu ,
Is it important to use CKEditor?
Did you tested Summernote?

Comment: not really, think i should try it.

Comment: I had a lot of problems with CKeditor in Laravel, I think go to Summernote, if you want help I'm here.

Comment: Thanks so much, I went for summernote and it solved my problem. Nevertheless, when I show image uploaded using summernote, it doesn't respect bootstrap grid system. I mean you have to scroll left-right to see full picture. Any remedy for that?

Comment: Ummm, No, I do not know anything about it, dear friend